# Chakra project or netinstall -- Arch Linux installation

Tags: install, arch-linux

My arch linux installation didn't go well (apparently I should have gone through netinstall instead of core). When I try again, should I use the Chakra project (which is supposedly easier), or should I use netinstall?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your level of knowledge about Linux/Unix but I noticed that there are 2 approaches to learning it 1. Install simple distribution (for ex. Ubuntu), use it (it should work out of box, so you can progress slowly when you have time) 2. Install low-level distribution with good community (for ex. Gentoo/Arch) and get it working (you will get into problems and solving them is part of the process). I haven't heard about Chakra project and I don't know about it's community but I don't think it is popular so I'd recommend against it if you want to learn Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Describe where you are stuck?

Core is fine, use ethernet cable for internet connection. Being new to linux, wifi install works for many out of the box, but if not it may frustrate a bit.
[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup]

You will need wpa_supplicant, wireless_tools, and the driver for your card. When you select packages from the ' [*]dev_base ' during the installation.

You'll want to try to install arch at least once successfully before moving to chakra since it's based on arch, if you have issues this will help you get used to *finding* answers.

Skim through the sections, then read the parts your not clear on.

[ https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide ]

It may also be a good choice to practice installing arch then chakra on virtual box *before* going live with your real system. Try to have another computer to read guides from while installing so you can troubleshoot.

Comment: [ https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Arch_Linux_Install_Guide ]